# I was trouble with tittle of the Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bubble-chart

http://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/akb4Lj61/

i want name of the tittle in inside the box presently i don't have date with me so,  i want to put the name of the tittle in inside the box.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'bubble',
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    zoomType: 'xy'
},

title: {
    text: 'No Date Available'
},



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case of no data for highcharts you may use this plugin 
[no-data-to-display.js](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'No Date Availavle'
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/b9k5avdj/   I added subtitle like this but i want improve font size and is this write or wrong.

Comment: in case of no data it's not right to change in highcharts data (subtitle) cause somehow you gonna need that subtitle in your usecase data.. so, its better to play with no-data-to-display plugin . you can easily customize that plugin as per your need..

Comment: Thanks @bijay raj